# Why am I still getting -[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

Getting the following error:

> -[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.

This is the code causing the problem:

```
-(void) showModalTime:(int)tag {

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 216)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200.0, 216.0);

    //  smaller for timePicker
    timePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 216);

    timePicker.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xeedd82);
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [timePicker setMinuteInterval:15];
    [timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [popoverView addSubview:timePicker];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    popoverController.delegate = (id)self;  //  <--  this is the line that's causing the crash
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 216) animated:NO];

    switch (tag)  {  //  displays the popover datepicker
        case 11:  //  store open time
            [timePicker setTag:11];
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tfShopOpens.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            break;
        case 12:  //  store close time
            [timePicker setTag:12];
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tfShopCloses.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            break;
    }

}
```

PopoverController is defined as an instance variable:

> @property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController;

I have marked the line causing the crash;  I changed all of my PopoverControllers to instance variables and the problem appeared solved, but now has reared it's ugly head.  What else can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check popoverController is visible or not in  **showModalTime** method because popoverController overwrite

```
  if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: I added it; not able to recreate the crash, but it looks like you nailed the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you synthesized the property? If not, you may now have a `popoverController` and a `_popoverController` variable...

Try change all references to `popoverController` to `self.popoverController`...

```
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
self.popoverController.delegate = (id)self;
[self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 216) animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be this: PopoverController can not find the delegate

Solution: make sure that you have declared delegates of popover in your viewController's .h file like..

```
@interface FooController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
    // ...
}
// ...
@end
```

Then implement delegate method in .m file like..

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // do something now that it's been dismissed
}
```

Change the line of assigning of delegate like..

```
[popoverController setDelegate:self];
```

Try this..

This may help you.............

Comment: No, the delegate has been assigned in the .h file... this is occurring while building the popover (as indicated in the code)

Comment: try to remove casting of (id) from the assigning of delegate like shown in edit...